# Why do Disks become polygons in RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to `RegionPlot` a reinforced concrete section, by drawing a polygon as a rectangular shape, and on top of that, a number of circles as `Disk` objects, but as soon as I have more than 3 `Disk`s, the disks become polygon shape instead of a round smooth circle.

Can you please shed some light on this issue?

```
(* Input: Points that makes up the perimeter of the concrete section *)
OuterPointList={{0, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, 500}, {0, 500}};

(* Input: Location of each rebar and its diameter *)
RebarList = { {{50,50}, 16}, {{250,50}, 24}, {{250, 400}, 24}, 
              {{50, 400}, 24}, {{150, 300}, 24} };

RegionConcSect=Polygon[OuterPointList];
CreateOneRebar[Rebar_]:=Disk[ Rebar[[1]],Rebar[[2]] ];
RegionRebar = Map[CreateOneRebar,RebarList];

RegionPlot[{RegionConcSect, RegionRebar}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: I think that this is due to confusion in `RegionPlot`, since you are providing it a nested list of regions, which is not really standard syntax. Use `Flatten@{RegionConcSect, RegionRebar}` as its argument instead. Here is [the result I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fLy7c.png).

Comment: @MarcoB It works like a champ ! Thank you very much ! What if I want the rebars as Black and the Rectangle as Blue in color ?

Comment: @N.T.C I'd suggest using two separate plots, then combining them with `Show`. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is due to confusion in `RegionPlot`, since you are providing it a nested list of regions, which is not really standard syntax.

You could use `Flatten@{RegionConcSect, RegionRebar}` as its argument, or alternatively construct separate plots for each region, then combine them with `Show`. This also has the advantage of allowing you finer control on the formatting of the individual plots:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[RegionConcSect, BoundaryStyle -> None],
 RegionPlot[RegionRebar, PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> None
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on solving the problem which doesn't resort to `Show`.

```
OuterPointList = {{0, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, 500}, {0, 500}};
RegionConcSect = Polygon[OuterPointList];

RebarList = 
  {{{50, 50}, 16}, {{250, 50}, 24}, {{250, 400}, 24}, 
   {{50, 400}, 24}, {{150, 300}, 24}};
RegionRebars = RegionUnion @@ Disk @@@ RebarList

RegionPlot[
  RegionDifference[RegionConcSect, RegionRebars],
    PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.95, 0.94, 0.91], (* color of concrete? *)
    Prolog -> {Black, Scale[RegionConcSect, .95, RegionCentroid[RegionConcSect]]},
    BoundaryStyle -> None,
    AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Since documentation for `RegionPlot[]` contains no examples nor synopses that describe how `RegionPlot` should be have on a region or a list of regions/`Graphics` primitives, I don't think one can say authoritatively that a list of disks is a nonstandard argument.  `RegionPlot[]` does accept a list as a single region to be plotted, and it treats it in a reasonable way, which I will explain below.

While the internal machinations are different, effectively what is plotted is

```
RegionPlot[{
  DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics@RegionConcSect],  (* could use DiscretizeRegion[] here *)
  DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics@RegionRebar]
  },
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Of course, any disk will be discretized as a polygon, but in this case, the results are unsatisfactory.

One straightforward way to get a better plot is to use `RegionUnion` on the rebar:

```
(* internally calls DiscretizeRegion[] on RegionUnion[] *)
RegionPlot[{RegionConcSect, RegionUnion @@ RegionRebar}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

One can use `PlotStyle -> {style1, style2}`, substituting whatever styles are desired for styling the rectangle and the disks.

My feeling is that a list of graphics primitives is intended to be supported. What is really missing (imo) is a way to pass discretization options, such as `MaxCellMeasure`, to `RegionPlot`. The first example above, which I will explain below, illustrates that the default behavior is understandable and that the user could adjust the behavior by setting `MaxCellMeasure` in the way a user sometimes has to set `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion` in plotting.  For instance, it would be nice to be able to achieve the following through options to `RegionPlot` without having to discretize graphics (or regions) explicitly.

```
RegionPlot[{
   DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics@RegionConcSect], 
   DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics@RegionRebar, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 10.}]
   },
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

To understand better what to expect from `RegionPlot`, here is an explanation of what is happening internally.  `RegionPlot` picks a `MaxCellMeasure` setting based on the bounds of the region being plotted.  The list `RegionRebar` is treated as a single object to be plotted, which has rather large bounds and gets a pretty big `MaxCellMeasure` setting.  By contrast, `RegionUnion @@ RegionRebar` evaluates to `RegionUnion[Disk[<>], Disk[<>],...]` and symbolically represents the union of several regions instead of a single graphics.  `RegionPlot` calls `DiscretizeRegion` on this, and the procedure that analyzes the union results in a finer discretization.  One might criticize the default behavior for not plotting the list like `RegionUnion @@ RegionRebar` instead of like `Graphics@RegionRebar`.