# How to control resolution/refinement when using RegionPlot on ImplicitRegion?

Tags: plotting, regions

When I do something like

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[ℛ, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 500]
```

I get a rendering that looks like this:

[image]

So you can clearly see some finite resolution there. It turns out that the `PlotPoints` setting makes no difference; I can set this to 5 or 5000, the plot remains the same. Is there a bug somewhere in there or am I missing something?

Comment: This really comes down to how to control the method used by RegionPlot, which would be a more generally useful question.  Use `Mesh -> All` to see what RegionPlot actually computes.  The result is sensitive to MaxRecursion.  It seems clear that RegionPlot uses entirely different methods with such an ImplicitRegion with no explicit bounds compared to `RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> All]`

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I tried setting the value of `MaxRecursion` to a value higherthan 5, but other than the plot taking forever to be generated, the rendering of the circle did not improve. Putting the region specification explicitly in the RegionPlot command helps, yes, and as you say, showing the mesh reveals that it is completely different in this case. However, this does not help when the region was defined elsewhere...

Comment: `Graphics` primitives are smoother: `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightBlue, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to override the default `MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity` that `RegionPlot` passes to `DiscretizeRegion` is to discretize the region explicitly first:

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, y}];
RegionPlot@ BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ℛ, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.02}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Note: There is no discussion in the docs for [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) about how to adjust `RegionPlot` for plotting regions given by the new (V10) region functionality (`ImplicitRegion`, `ParametricRegion`,...), which [I've mentioned before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120759/why-do-disks-become-polygons-in-regionplot/120816#120816).  I don't believe there are any examples of the use of options other than `PlotRange` and `Epilog`, although some other options such as `PlotStyle` seem to work.  It just makes me wonder if it has been fully incorporated yet.)

Comment: Thanks very much. Tremendously helpful and competent answer. As always...