# How to make a region smoother

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.1.1**

---

In the tutorial *Solving PDE with Finite Elements* at the documentation center, there is this code:

```
Ω = 
  ImplicitRegion[! ((x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 <= 3^2), {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 
     10}}];
RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

This is supposed to look like this:

[image: region 1]

But when I run the same code on my Mathematica 10.3, I get this:

[image]

What is going on? How to make it just like it is given in the documentation center? I guess there is a precision setup?

---

Update: I ran this code in Wolfram Programming Lab online and the problem is the same. Also, I updated to Mathematica 11.1. The problem is still there.

Comment: looks ok on mathematica 10.4

Comment: @Jenny_mathy, I just ran it on Mathematica 11 and I still have the same problem. It is probably not version dependent at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: I get the same issue (Mac/MMa 11.1). Oddly, the problem goes away if you plot from `{y, -3, 13}` but shows oddities on both sides if you plot from `{y, -2, 12}`.

Comment: @bills, this bug gives me trouble with solving a Laplace equation over a region with a circular part that I made using "Disk". It is the post from yesterday [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144279/boundary-condition-setup-for-the-region-defined-with-basic-geometry). I see that if I make a "Disk", it is not nearly as smooth as I would want it to be (or as it is shown in tutorials).

Comment: Somewhere on this site is a similar issue.  Use `DiscretizeRegion[]` or `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]` with appropriate options.  You can then `RegionPlot[]` its result, if you like.

Comment: Here it is: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125461/how-to-control-resolution-refinement-when-using-regionplot-on-implicitregion

Comment: This is a bug and you should report it to WRI.

Comment: @user21, I am collecting data. I will report it soon. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Same problem and solution as [How to control resolution/refinement when using RegionPlot on ImplicitRegion?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125461/how-to-control-resolution-refinement-when-using-regionplot-on-implicitregion/125506#125506):

```
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion@Ω, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am probably wrong but it seems that this provides a nice way to plot it only. What if I need to use this region for boundary conditions to solve a PDE? How would you do that for a question here? [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144279/boundary-condition-setup-for-the-region-defined-with-basic-geometry)

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov Yes, I wondered if plotting was the main concern. For plotting and geometrical applications, `DiscretizeRegion` is a typical top-level function. For `NDSolve` and the [tag:finite-element-method], [`ToElementMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) and related functions in the ``NDSolve`FEM` `` context allow better control over setting up PDEs. The easiest way is probably the options [`"MeshOptions"` and `MashCellMeasure`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MeshOptions+MaxCellMeasure+NDSolve), but other ways exist.